# invoking method using ajax at code behind in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

hey i am making a simple web form its a  product detail insertion web page. I am trying to insert using ajax call. without ajax it works .. but $.ajax is not invoking my code behind static method, no idea wat's the issue. here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var cat = document.getElementById('DropDownList1').value;
        var nm = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var cde = document.getElementById('code').value;
        var dt = document.getElementById('dt').value;

        var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var f3 = document.getElementById('ty').innerHTML;

        alert("you clicked " + cat + " - " + nm + "-" + cde + "-" + dt + 
                "-" + price + "-" + f3 +  "-");

       //////////////uptil here alert gives the right value.

       $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json", 
           url: "home.aspx/ins",
           dataType: "json",
           data: "{'Name :' + nm + 'code :' + cde +'category :'+ cat + 
              'date :'+ dt +'price :'+ pr +'img_name :' + f3}",
           //data:"{}",
           //async: false,
           success: function (response) {
               alert("User has been added successfully.");
               window.location.reload();
           }
       });
    })
});
```

---

```
//////////////////////////////// here is the code behind method:

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ins(string Name,string code,string category, DateTime date,
   int price,string img_name)
{
    productclass pc = new productclass();
    pc.Pr_name = Name;
    pc.Code = code;
    pc.Category = category;
    pc.Expiry = date;
    pc.Price = price;
    pc.Pr_image = img_name;

    dalinsert di = new dalinsert();
    bool flag = di.insert(pc);
}
```

Comment: Could be an issue with your data input.  Try building your input as a javascript object and then convert it to a string with JSON.stringify(variable) for safety and less work on you.  Which looking closer I believe is your issue.  Your trying to concatenate within a string.  You are not terminating your "" before doing the +.  In any case, JSON.stringify() is usually cleaner.

Comment: oka will try it ...  but input is working fine, since i am already getting values in alert . oka thanks

Comment: Your alert would work fine because you are concatenating properly there ("something" + "something else").  But in your data you are doing. " 'something' + variable + 'something else' ".  The string enclosure there is "", not '' so to contatenate in that case it would have to be (" 'something' " + " 'something else ' ").  So essentially as you have it now in your data part, the + are treated as literals, not operators.

Comment: @Kam just after the alert, define  `var data = {'Name': nm, 'code': cde, 'category': cat, 'date': dt, 'price': pr, 'img_name': f3};`  and then in your ajax, do `data: data` See if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to pass data to ajax post via webmethod is like this.

`var params = "{'Name' :'" + nm + "', 'code' :'" + cde + "', 'category' :'" + cat + "', 'date' : '" + dt + ", 'price' :'" + pr + "' , 'img_name' :'" + f3 + "' }"` // Declare this above `$.ajax...`

`data: params,` //Use above in `$.ajax...` .

Comment: that was helpful.just tell me how would i access params in the code behind static method.  like wat should be method argument and how to access parameters with in params.thanks

Comment: @Kam It is same as you have used/declare in question, there is no change to param in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your data being passed in:

```
data: "{'Name :' + nm + 'code :' + cde +'category :'+ cat +'date :'+ dt +'price :'+ pr +'img_name :' + f3}"
```

I see two possible issues there.  First, your '+' are being treated as literals there as they are surrounded by double quotes that are never escaped.  What you are trying to achieve, I believe, is:

```
data: "{'Name :'"+ nm +"'code :'"+ cde +"'category :'"+ cat +"'date :'"+ dt +"'price :'"+ pr +"'img_name :'"+ f3 +"}"
```

However that still has a potential problem as I believe that json will be malformed.  The expected syntax of a json string, with string variables at least, is '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'.

A better way to make sure your right and to save yourself work is to use JSON.stringify to do the work for you.

```
var temp = {};
temp.Name = nm;
temp.code = cde;
temp.category = cat;
temp.date = dt;
temp.price = pr;
temp.img_name = f3;
var data = JSON.stringify(temp);
```

Comment: thanks ... one thing. how to access this temp variable in my code behind static method.. i can't access it how to it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with asp so unsure how you would access that input on the back end. Once the request is made to the back end, it should be the same as any other post request made to your server.  You'd access it the same way.  There would not be a 'temp' variable at that point, just the internal variables provided to the post